# GWT AbstractCell - render an image with a URL and include an error handler?

Tags: image, gwt, grid

GWT's AbstractCell allows you to create custom cells, including the ability to render an image in the cell.  Is there a way to render an image by setting it's URL property **and** have an error handler associated with it (to take action in the event the image resource is not available or has a problem loading)?  In testing the image properties render properly but it doesn't appear that the error handler is included.

Here is the example code I'm attempting to use:

```
new AbstractCell<String>() {
  @Override
  public void render (Context context, String value, final SafeHtmlBuilder sb) {
    final Image testImage = new Image();
    testImage.addErrorHandler(new ErrorHandler() {
      @Override
      public void onError(ErrorEvent event) {
        // image SRC failed to load so pick a different image and set the tool tip
        testImage.setResource(images.errorLoading()); // from an image bundle
        testImage.setTitle("Image Load Failed");
      }
    });
    // the value passed in is the image src
    testImage.setUrl(value); 
    sb.append(SafeHtmlUtils.fromTrustedString(testImage.toString()));
 }
```

I think the problem resides in the `testImage.toString()`.  To implement the AbstractCell you must append to the SafeHtmlBuilder.  When using the `toString()` method on the image, the image URL is set correctly and other attributes are set correctly, but the Error Handler is not included in the `toString()` method (as best I can tell).  Is there another way to go about this?

Answer (score 1):

`testImage.toString()` method creates a simple HTML string that is rendered within a cell. There will be no handlers in this HTML.

You can set URL to your testImage outside of the `render()` method. Give browser time to load image (you may have to use Scheduler). Then you refresh/draw your Cell widget. I am not sure, though, if users would appreciate a lag until all images load.

Consider using ImageLoadingCell instead.

Comment: I'm not able to set the URL outside of the render method as the abstract cell is being inserted into a grid and the String value passed into the cell represents the image URL (they are dynamic on a per-row basis).  I've also looked at ImageLoadingCell but I don't see how that will help me in this case (it ultimately would require me to have the image be part of a bundle (not possible in this case since the images are loaded per-row based on the URL passed in).  Unless I'm missing something?

Comment: You can set URL outside of render() method in your use case, but I suggest using ImageCell or ImageLoadingCell. These cells do exactly what you are trying to do: they show an image by its URL (unlike ImageResourceCell). Then you can override the `onBrowserEvent` method in the cell to show an error image/message if the required image cannot be loaded. In general, you never need to set handlers in each row of a grid: you only need to override a method in a cell itself (i.e. `getValue`, `update`, `onBrowserEvent`, etc.)

Comment: Can you provide an example of how you would set the URL outside the `render()` method?  As I said the cell is going into a grid so I don't have knowledge of or access to the image URL prior to the grid being constructed.  Also I'm not able to find a good example on how you set up an ImageLoadingCell with an image and specify the URL.  I follow adding the `onBrowserEvent` method but cannot find a good example of using one of these cells instead of an AbstractCell.